# discord.py on_member_update activity time

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get time spent in an activity (playing league of legends).

but I keep getting this error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start' referenced before assignment`

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing" and str(i.name) == "League of Legends"]
        game_before = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing" and str(i.name) == "League of Legends"]
        
        
        if game_after:
            print(game_after)
            start = time.time()
             
        elif game_before and not game_after:
            end = time.time()
            total = end - start
            print(total)
```

---

---

---

I tried doing this, but now if a member starts playing league, `start = time.time()` runs and then when they stop playing it will run `start = 0` and then `elif game_before` so `total` would be same as end time

````
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing" and str(i.name) == "League of Legends"]
        game_before = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing" and str(i.name) == "League of Legends"]
        
        start = 0
        if game_after:
            start = time.time()
             
        elif game_before:
            end = time.time()
            total = end - start
            hours, rem = divmod(total, 3600)
            minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
            print("{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))```
````

Comment: `start` is only referenced if `game_after` is True. try setting `start` as None or a default value outside the if. Also, you don't need `not game_after` in the elif check as its an elif, and will only be executed if the first if is not true. Another thing, I see you're trying to print the time the user plays the game. You would have to save `start` to a json file, database or make it global to use it again when the user changes activity.

Comment: Yeah, because I want `start` to be when they start the activity.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement you assign the start variable, but in your elif statement you're using the start variable without it being assigned.

You should probably initiate the variable on the first line, like "start = 0"

Comment: Because `if game_after` always runs before `elif game_before` and I want the start time to be when `game_after`

Comment: Then it won't be an issue by giving start an initial value, as the initial value wont be used.
As the comment says  above, you could also define the variable as None

Comment: I iniated the variable on first line and now but if member changes activity `start = 0` will run everytime